# Why related data is included although told not to do in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following code to retrieve the `discussionwalls` created by a specific teacher (foreign key is CreatedBy). Each discussionwall can have many `TimeFrames` as well.

When I serialize the `discussionwalls`, I see that I have the associated `Teacher` for each `DiscussionWall` item, and inside each Teacher I have `OwnedDiscussionWalls` back again, and this is causing trouble in json output.

Can someone explain me why I have the related entity (`Teacher`) in my result set although I do not have `Include()` statement for it?

```
var discussionwalls = db.DiscussionWalls.Include(dw => dw.Timeframes)
                        .Where(dw => dw.CourseId == courseid)
                        .Where(dw => dw.CreatedBy == currUserId)
                        .ToList();
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
      PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
      ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(discussionwalls, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);

return json;
```

Here is the related section of the Teacher class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public List<DiscussionWall> OwnedDiscussionWalls { get; set; }

    public List<DiscussionTimeframe> TimeframesCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the related section of the DiscussionWall class:

```
public class DiscussionWall
{
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public List<DiscussionTimeframe> Timeframes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you access the database any time before you query for DiscussionWalls?

Comment: This is actually the first attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add [JsonIgnore] on your property Teacher in DiscussionWall.

```
    public class DiscussionWall
    {
        [Required]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

        public List<DiscussionTimeframe> Timeframes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What if I need `Teacher ` later for another purpose?

Comment: use property `CreatedBy` to get `Teacher` when you need?

Comment: so, you mean `JsonIgnore ` will not cause a trouble?

Comment: `JsonIgnore` means when `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` the object will ignore this propery.
reference: [http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size]

Answer (score 1):

The serializer is causing the Teacher entity to be lazy loaded by simply accessing the property.  Turn off lazy loading or add an explicit select to your linq query.

Comment: `discussionwalls` already has the Teacher entity before the serializer actually. I have placed the following configuration in the dbcontext class, but still has the save problem: `public gEchoLuDBContext()            : base("gEchoLuMaster") {           this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;       }`